# What system resources are used when a web part is closed instead of deleted?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

I'm trying to figure out what exactly the difference is between a web part that is open on the page versus a web part that has been closed instead of deleted.

I can only find this [article on technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg153557.aspx) which has this interesting quote:

> Note that in SharePoint Server 2010, a
>   closed Web part no longer consumes the
>   same system resources as open Web
>   parts.

My question has two parts:

1. What is the difference between an open web part and a closed one? (Besides the contents being visible of course)
2. In a custom web part, is there a best practice for preventing the web part from executing in the event that a user closes it?

I am looking for answers regarding SharePoint 2007 MOSS or WSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in SharePoint 2007 Open web part and close web parts differ only by the contents is not visible in case of closed web part

i don't think you can do any thing in case of MOSS 2007

Comment: There isn't any way to detect when a web part is closed?

Comment: there are two classes SPWebPartManager and SPLimitedWebPartManager out of which SPWebPartManager  is not advised to use in code due to thread safety while SPLimitedWebPartManager does not provide much power as of SPWebPartManager you can try using  SPLimitedWebPartManager  and see if this can help you out in any way